# Problems using git diff to create file list for deploy

Tags: git, bash, deployment, shell, release-management

I want to use something like the following command to create a tarball to deploy:

```
tar cjvf ~/deploy.tar.bz2 `git diff --name-only 0abc 1def`
```

The inner git diff command produces a list of files with relative including the relative path when i run it separately.

I'm running into two problems though, I need to be able to auto escape spaces in the output, so tar doesn't complain about files containing spaces <strike>and when the tar does get created, all the files have a duplicate 'hidden file' preceded by a '.' that don't show up with ls -al</strike>. These are OSX specific metafiles as noted by kch.

Anyway, does anyone know of the solution to these problems, or is there just a plain easier way to script this?

Comment: BTW, I often deploy via push and use post-receive hooks to deal with updating the tree, restarting the app, etc. It's really fast and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I may look into doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I settled on the following solution with sed.

```
tar cjf ~/deploy.tar.bz2 \
`git diff --name-only 0abc 1def|sed -e "s/ /\\\ /g"`
```

Answer (score 3):

The hidden dot-files, are they dot-underscore-files?

If for file `foo` you have another `._foo`, and you're on a Mac, the dot-underscore file is where the file resource fork / metadata is kept.

As for the git output, might try piping it through `sed` or `perl` for quoting. I believe `xargs` could help here too.

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use `--files-from=FILE` or `-T FILE` option of tar, where FILE can be '-' to signify standard input?

```
 git diff --name-only 0abc 1def | tar -T - cjf ~/deploy.tar.bz2
```

You shouldn't have problem with spaces or tabs in filenames, or with single quotes, or backquotes, or backslashes (I think your solution would have problems with single quote "'" in filename). You might have problem with newlines in filenames, just like in IFS solution.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. If I run into more trouble, I'll probably just look at sanitizing names to alphanumeric strings.

Comment: This worked great (not to mention simpler than the other answers), except tar on Ubuntu wants a dash in front of the command. I.e: `tar -T - -cf` instead of `tar -T - cf`.

Answer (score 0):

If size doesn't matter you could use **git archive**.

I'm not sure if it's possible to create a tarball containing only the differences between two commits.

Comment: That would work, but I want to avoid having to re-deploy files that don't contain changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
eval tar cjvf ~/deploy.tar.bz2 `git diff --name-only 0abc 1def | while read x; do echo "'""$x""'"; done`
```

or try the same thing using sed, or

```
IFS='
' tar cjvf ~/deploy.tar.bz2 `git diff --name-only 0abc 1def`
```

Note that there is only a single newline in IFS.

However, if the name of your files contain newlines, you're doomed.

Comment: Doesn't work, I don't think that the quoting is evaluated the same way after being fed through the pipe.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have edited the post to make it work, one solution with eval, another using the IFS variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, more elegant solution that works around escaping spaces in the filenames

```
git diff --name-only 0abc 1def | \
    tr '\n' '\0' | \
    xargs -0 tar -rjvf ~/deploy.tar.bz2
```

As jpalecek pointed out, one wold not want to run "tar -c..." multiple times, it's better to use -r.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. xargs doesn't give you any guarantee to run the command only once, so you could end up with tar running multiple times, and archive containing only files from the last batch.