# Python tar file module shows two files with same name, except one begins with _

Tags: python, tarfile

I have a tarfile with 3 files in it, file1, file2, file3. When I use the Python tarfile module to view the files in the tarfile, the module shows 6 files, the three that I have, and it prepends an underscore to each of them. I am not sure why.

```
infile = '/Users/myname/Downloads/tt/testing.tar.gz'

outdir = '/Users/myname/Downloads/tt/out'

tar_flag = tarfile.is_tarfile(infile)

if tar_flag:
    tar_obj = tarfile.open(infile, 'r')
    name_list = tar_obj.getnames()
    for name in name_list:
        print name
    tar_obj.close()
```

This prints the following:

```
./._file1
./file1
./._file2
./file2
./._file3
./file3
```

However, when I check the contents of the tarfile using the tar command, there are only 3 files in the tar file:

```
$ tar tvf testing.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  0 myname staff       0 Nov  7 10:20 ./
-rw-r--r--  0 myname staff  518458 Jun  4 08:37 ./file1
-rw-r--r--  0 myname staff 1050412 Oct 20 14:16 ./file2
-rw-r--r--  0 myname staff  132463 Nov  7 10:08 ./file3
```

Also, when I extract the tar file, there are only 3 files in it.

I am not sure why tarfile module is prepending the _ and showing the filenames twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `tar`-specific issue but rather about your OS. From your paths I assume you are using a Mac computer.

The files with the `._` prefix are the [AppleDouble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats) resource fork files for storing macOS's extended file attributes (including those normally manipulated with the `xattr` command). You will also see such files appearing when you copy files to an external FAT32/ExFAT drive.

After unpacking the files, since your Mac uses HFS+ or APFS which supports those extended attributes, those files are instead stored directly in the filesystem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323580/what-are-all-these-hidden-prefixed-files-that-are-in-my-git-repo) is another question about these files.